# Laravel updateOrCreate only if column type equals color

Tags: php, laravel

I have a problem, I need update record if only in request I get value == color. How I can do it? I have code:

```
    $shop->services()->updateOrCreate([
        'user_id' => $user->id,
        'shop_id' => $shop->id,
        'service_data' => $request->service_type == 'color' ? : false, //do update for record only if service_data == 'color'
    ], [
        'price' => $price,
        'valid_until' => Carbon::now()->addDays($request->valid_until),
        'service_data' => $request->service_data == 'color' ?: false, //do update for record only if service_data == 'color'
    ]);
```

How I can do it?

Comment: Wouldn't this make more sense as an if statement around your `updateOrCreate` call? Something like `if($request->service_data == "color"){ $shop->services()->updateOrCreate(...); }`

Answer (score 0):

You could use `when`:

```
$shop->services()->when($request->input('service_data', false) === 'color', function($query) {
    return $query->update([
        'user_id' => $user->id,
        'shop_id' => $shop->id,
        'service_data' => 'color'
    ], [
        'price' => $price,
        'valid_until' => Carbon::now()->addDays($request->valid_until),
        'service_data' => 'color'
    ]);
})
->when($request->input('service_data', false) !== 'color', function($query) {
    return $query->create([
        'user_id' => $user->id,
        'shop_id' => $shop->id,
        'service_data' => false
    ], [
        'price' => $price,
        'valid_until' => Carbon::now()->addDays($request->valid_until),
        'service_data' => false
    ]);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

KISS priciple -> Keep it simple and stupid

```
if ($request->service_data == 'color') {
   $shop->services()->updateOrCreate([
        'user_id' => $user->id,
        'shop_id' => $shop->id,
        'service_data' => $request->service_type
        'price' => $price,
        'valid_until' => Carbon::now()->addDays($request->valid_until),
        'service_data' => $request->service_data
    ]);
}
```